# How can I make my image gallery slider loop through without reversing the animation once I reach the last image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the codepen of the gallery https://codepen.io/designextras/pen/VweLbNW

Once you get to the last image, instead of animating to the next one it animates, but goes in reverse and basically shows all the previous images we just clicked through, and then shows the first image again. So imagine I have 100 images it would go reverse and show all 100 before showing the starting image.

I'm not sure how to make it go from image 1,2,3,4 then only show 1 without showing images 3,2 first.

this code is what makes the reverse animation occur, but if I remove it it looks like it achieves the effect I want when it just goes 1,2,3,4, then 1 without showing 3,2 but then there's no animation and I eventually want to add new effects and customizations.

```
 .slide {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 }
```

Also, when I click the next or previous button it updates every single picture with the same index value, so maybe there's a way to create a JS function that only updates the image I am on with the index vs all of them to solve this? I don't know how I'd write that or if they would even solve the problem

[image]

is this a problem on my javascript? or CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but you can have the transition on a separate class in your CSS and then add/remove this class depending on the counter. So if you're on the first slide, add the class, and then remove it when you get to the end so there won't be a transition from the last slide to the first.

In your CSS:

```
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.transition {
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

In your JS:

```
function slider() {
  //add the class at the beginning of the slideshow
  if (counter === 1) {
    slides.forEach(function (slide, index) {
      slide.classList.add("transition");
    });
  }
  //remove the class at the end of the slideshow
  if (counter === slides.length) {
    slides.forEach(function (slide, index) {
      slide.classList.remove("transition");
    });
    counter = 0;
  }
  if (counter < 0) {
    counter = slides.length - 1;
  }

  slides.forEach(function (slide) {
    slide.style.transform = `translateX(-${counter * 100}%)`;
  });
}
```

Comment: the only issue is when it resets back to 1, the animation disappears so it looks weird when it resets. I'm trying to figure out how to maintain the fluid animation once it completes through the loop. Also, if you click the previous button the animation repeats that same reverse effect so it would need to work for both the next button and previous button

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't read the last part of your post. In that case, I don't know. Hopefully someone else will have the answer.